# How do I use UISearchBar to search the web?

Tags: ios4, keyboard, iphone, uisearchbar

I want to use the UISearchBar and used its text which further can be put into a url and that url will search the web. I am unable to dismiss the keyboard. I have tried using the first responder thng but that doesn't seems to work. I am new to iPhone development and fairly new to programming world so please bear with me. any help would be appritiated.

Comment: @tushar: you are rightly using that resign first responder but what matters is that are you using that at the right place. That means you called resignFirstResponder method to the searchBar field but check it if it is the firstResponder at that time. I think That is the problem there.

Answer (score 1):

Add a search bar delegate to `yourclass.h` as following:

```
@interface yourclass : yourviewcontroller < UISearchBarDelegate >
```

Then, implement this function of the delegate into `yourclass.m`:

```
(void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
   [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
   //your code
}
```

Comment: @Tushar>: you can mark this answer as the right one if it's so, thanks !